# How to enable Docker remote API on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows-10

I set docker daemon item and add: "host:[tcp://0.0.0.0:4243]"

[image]
type  http://10.0.75.1:4243/images/json on Chrome.

But it doesn't not work.

Comment: give a more information about you problem, thеn anybody can help you. add error messages.

Comment: What do you exatly want do do?

Comment: i want to integrate docker with idea